# How to retrieve index based worker attributes in the workflow configuration in Twilio

Tags: twilio

I have worker attributes in the Twilio console like this:

`{"contact_uri":"client:testuser", "call_group":[10,11], "call_group_priority":{"10":1,"11":2},"task_types" : ["task1","task2"]}`

Here, call_group_priority is a json array where key is call_group and value is priority and I want to get priority based on key and use in the workflow configuration for ordering all workers for that call group. To achieve this, I used following line in the workflow configuration:

`"order_by":"worker.call_group_priority[task.selected_call_group_id] ASC",`

But, when I try to update workflow configuration using command, I get error. That error is because of index based order by.

How can I implement order_by in the workflow configuration like I mentioned above. Any answer would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you solve this at all? If not, can you tell me the exact error you're getting? Thanks

Comment: No, I talked to one of the Twilio guy called Alex. He said, twilio does not support retrieval  of index based worker attributes in the workflow configuration. I have changed my design. Thanks

Comment: Cool, thanks for letting me know. Glad you're able to move on!

Comment: @philnash can i make a conference call using some admin user and bring agent and customer to that conference call without keeping them on hold? I am trying to implement live listen and barge in functionality using conference. but there are few obstacles. Your suggestion or ideas would be helpful. Thanks

Comment: Yes, you can do that. I believe you're looking for Agent Conference features. Check out the blog post and resources linked here and let me know if that helps: https://www.twilio.com/blog/2017/12/agent-conference-generally-available.html

Comment: Thank you so much, I will check it.

Comment: @philnash The scenario is, a customer is on a call with an agent. Agent is handling the customer call from web. Now supervisor wants to get into that call and listen what they are talking without letting them know. To achieve this, Supervisor created a conference call using number in twilio and then customer call is updated by getting the callSid and brought that into newly created conference call. And it worked, i as a supervisor was able to talk customer but an agent which was handling call previously got disconnected Agent just went to wrap-up state. Is there any other way to achieve this?

Comment: Ah, do you start the call by just connecting the two callers (ie `<Dial><Number>` or `<Dial><Client>`?) It's best if they connect as a `<Conference>` in the first place, that way no-one gets kicked off the call.